# Error when querying a SQL Server view with whitespace in the name

Tags: sql-server, powershell

**Edit: It was a !@#$ typo. In addition to the whitespace, the problem view used a hyphen where the naming convention required an underscore. Somehow I missed it.**

I'm using Powershell to test queries on certain SQL Server tables and views, one of which has whitespace in its name. The schema looks like this:

```
TABLE_CATALOG  TABLE_SCHEMA  TABLE_NAME     TABLE_TYPE
-------------  ------------  ----------     ----------
my_database    dbo           my_table       BASE TABLE
my_database    dbo           my_view        VIEW
my_database    dbo           my_other view  VIEW
```

This script works perfectly on tables:

```
$table = "my_table"
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table"
$server = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("my_server")
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database
$db = $server.Databases.Item("my_database")
$dt = $db.ExecuteWithResults($query)
$dt.Tables[0] | Format-Table
```

But if I change line 1 to `$table = "my_view"`, I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteWithResults" with "1" argument(s): "Execute with results failed for Database 'my_database'. "
At line:6 char:1
+ $dt = $db.ExecuteWithResults($query)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException
```

It works, though, when I enclose the view name in square brackets:

```
$table = "[my_view]"
```

However, `$table = "[my_other view]"` still throws that error.

What is the correct syntax to query a view with a space in the name?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the syntax:

```
$table = "['my_other view']"
```

Where you use single quotes around the table name inside of square brackets.

Comment: Thanks. This would have worked. The problem was a rogue hyphen in that view's name (in addition to the whitespace). The naming convention is underscores, and I somehow didn't notice.

Comment: You are not the first person not notice that subtle difference.  I do not like underscores because if they are used in hyperlinks, you cannot easily tell if it is a space or underscore.  Hence, my std is hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was a stupid, stupid typo. The problem view had a long name with a hyphen where the naming convention called for an underscore. I was focused on the whitespace and somehow missed it.